# To grep version number from Wordpress plugin folder

Tags: grep, regular-expression

What will be grep regex to extract version number like

```
 Version: 3.1.5
 * Version: 3.1.5
```

Will output   **3.1.5**

But It should not catch likes

```
MIME-Version: 1.0\n
```

Here is my grep command

```
grep -ri 'version\s*:\s*[0-9\.]\w*' /home/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name
```

**not working**

```
grep -Po "(^|\s)+(Version: )\K([0-9]|\.)*(?=\s|$)" /home/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/
```

`woocommerce` is a folder. There is file `woocommerce.php` under this folder.

**Content of `woocommerce.php`**

```
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce
 * Plugin URI: http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/
 * Description: An e-commerce toolkit that helps you sell anything. Beautifully.
 * Version: 2.3.8
 * Author: WooThemes
 * Author URI: http://woothemes.com
 * Requires at least: 4.0
 * Tested up to: 4.2
```

**Working**

```
grep -rPo "(^|\s|^\*)+(Version\s*:\s*)\K([0-9]|\.)*(?=\s|$)" /home/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/attachments/
```

Comment: The command is working well....while checking for files inside a directory run it as `grep -rPo .... /directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
grep -Po "(?<=Version: )([0-9]|\.)*(?=\s|$)"
```

If you have `MIME-Version: 1.0` instead of `MIME-Version: 1.0\n`:

```
grep -Po "(^|\s)+(Version: )\K([0-9]|\.)*(?=\s|$)"
```

**Explanation :**

- `-P` stands for PCRE, `-o` for taking only the matched portion of the line
- `(^|\s)+(Version: )` will match `Version` at the start or one or more whitespaces, the `\K` will then discard the match
- `([0-9]|\.)*` will match any digit or `.` zero or more times, this is what we want
- The previous token will be followed by either any whitespace character or end of the line

**Test:**

```
$ cat file.txt 
 Version: 3.1.5
 * Version: 3.1.5
MIME-Version: 1.0\n

$ grep -Po "(?<=Version: )([0-9]|\.)*(?=\s|$)" file.txt 
3.1.5
3.1.5



$ cat file.txt 
Version: 3.1.5
 * Version: 3.1.5
MIME-Version: 1.0

$ grep -Po "(^|\s)+(Version: )\K([0-9]|\.)*(?=\s|$)" file.txt 
3.1.5
3.1.5
```

Comment: This will still catch the `MIME-Version:` if it doesn't have `\n` on the end,which I think must be a typo as it seems very odd.

Comment: @JID: well, i have taken OP's examples literally..anyway i have modified the answer..

Comment: i want to search in all files under folder plugin_name. I have updated question for it.

Comment: @WaseemShaikh Then use `grep -rPo ...... /path/to/plugin_name`

Comment: @WaseemShaikh: It must work..check my example..i have shown that already..

Comment: `@heemayl` : worked with slight modification. Could you please explain the regex.

Comment: @WaseemShaikh: Could you tell what modification you have made ?

Comment: `Version\s*:\s*` . Please explain you regex.

Comment: @WaseemShaikh: check my edits..

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like

```
grep -w Version: /home/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name |grep -v -- -Version|awk '{print $NF}'
```

Comment: It is not working for either of valid string

Comment: You are right, it will work for Version: 3.1.5, but not for * Version: 3.1.5. Check my updated answer

Comment: @JID, your code maybe need small correction. You expect to have space symbol before Version keyword

Comment: @RomeoNinov 0 or more matches,your will match `MIME-Version:` tbh though it would probably be better to use `awk '/[^[:graph:]]Version/{print $NF}'`

Comment: @JID  no, you do not read the key I add to grep!!!

Comment: still not working `grep -w Version: /home/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce |awk '{print $NF}'`

Comment: @RomeoNinov you realise a hyphen is a valid character in a word ?

Comment: Edited, now should work

Comment: What if it was `A.Version:` this is a pretty flimsy solution.

Comment: @JID, this you offer is odd. Do you want to push your way and kickoff the other answers?

Comment: huh? I just thought after suggesting that your answer does not work, and you not correcting it, i would provide a valid,durable one.

Comment: What I want to say is using dot and underscore in definitions is very odd and IMHO in some cases impossible

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
awk '/[^[:graph:]]Version/{print $NF}' file
```

---

Example

**Input**

```
 Version: 3.1.5
 * Version: 3.1.5
MIME-Version: 1.0
J_Version: 7.25
A.Version: 50
```

**Output**

```
3.1.5
3.1.5
```